# C++ macro adding to std::map

Tags: c++, macros

I'm very new to C++. I just started to pick it up this last week or so.

I am trying to write a macro to be able to access and add items to a std::map. However, I'm not finding this to work. What am I doing wrong or is there a better way to implement this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

typedef struct {
  std::string name;
  int value;
} Token;

std::map<std::string, Token> ALL_TOKENS;

#define T(macro, name, value) \
  Token macro {name, value}; \
  ADD(name, macro); \
  T(TEST, "Test", 1); \

#define ADD(str, tok) \
  ALL_TOKENS.insert(std::pair<std::string, Token>(str, tok)); \

#define GET(str) \
  ALL_TOKENS[str]; \

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  Token tok = GET("Test");
  printf("%s", tok.name.c_str());
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there a better way? I can hardly think of a *worse* way...

Comment: @KerrekSB Ok...? I'm new to c++. I just picked it up last week.

Comment: Forget about macros and focus on classes

Comment: Looks like you created more work with the macros than you are benefiting from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, your macros make the code more difficult to understand. It also looks to me like you don't entirely understand `std::map` yet.

When I use `map`, I *usually* use `operator[]` for insertion, and possibly for retrieving as well. It's usually easiest if you think of it just as an array that can use essentially any (sortable) type as a subscript.

For example, to count how often each word occurs in a file, you could do something like this:

```
std::string word;
std::map<std::string, size_t> counts;

while (infile >> word)
    ++counts[word];
```

Then you could print out all the words and how often each was found (in alphabetical order) with code something like this:

```
for (auto const &w : counts)
    std::cout << w.first << "\t" << w.second << "\n";
```

At least to me, this seems simpler and more understandable than any code I could write using your macros.

Comment: Thanks you're response helped the most.

Answer (score 0):

Disregarding the poor choice of using macros to access functionality...

You are not getting any output since you have not added anything to the map.

Try

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  Token t{"Test", 10};
  ADD("Test", t);
  Token tok = GET("Test");
  printf("%s\n", tok.name.c_str());
  return 0;
}
```

You'll get some output.